# How to cite/credit a photograph using Turabian?

Tags: citations, citation-style, graphics, history

I contacted some owner of some historical photographs and obtained permission to use them in my work.

They asked I put a line under the photograph to indicate simply author and photo number (they have assigned IDs to each photo). They said I'm free to decide precisely the wording of the credit.

My paper follows Turabian format. Does that specify the way to word the credit appearing under the photograph? In addition, should I also give a Turabian-style footnote, along with a bibliographic entry along with? The author didn't say the latter was needed, but I can't see how it doesn't get cited, when a photo conveys information just as text conveys information, just in a different way.

How do I cite and/or credit a photograph that I have permission to use, using Turabian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the [Turabian Tip Sheet on Figures & Captions](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/dam/jcr:05ce58b0-afeb-49eb-ab54-3bfc416862a8/Turabian-Tip-Sheet-9.pdf) be of help?

The pattern is:

```
Figure {Number}. {Description of the picture}. Photograph by {Name}, {Date}. {Source}. {ID}.
```

The example provided by the tip sheet is:

> Figure 3.1. *Helpers in a Georgia Cotton Mill*. Photograph by Lewis W. Hine, January 19, 1909. The National Child Labor Committee Collection, Library of Congress Prints and Photographs Division, Washington, DC. LC-DIG-nclc-01581.

No footnote and no bibliographic entry is needed.